# linux - should be a file pdo_mysql.so under php/modules? i have only pdo.so and pdo_sqlite

Tags: php, linux, symfony4

After updating PHP to 7.3 (linux).

I get error:

> An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver.

Could it be because of PDO?

In my folder php/modules I don't find pdo_mysql.so. Should it be there?

Comment: It depends if it was installed when you installed PHP. Did you install PHP yourself? Or via an operating system package? Which version of Linux are you using, precisely? And which package(s) did you install?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in file `php.ini` uncommented string `extension=pdo_mysql`. This file can be located in the `/etc/php/7.3/cli` or in `/etc/php/7.3/apache2` directory depending on which package you installed.